# Condensing a list of lists in python by duplicates in a certain column

Tags: python

So, I have a list of lists in python like so:

```
[[a, foo, bar], [a, dog, cat], [b, foo, bar], [c, foo, bar]]
```

And I want to condense it in to the following:

```
[[a, bar, cat], [b, bar], [c, bar]]
```

Where the last two indexes of the 'a' object are the 3rd columns from the first and second instances of the 'a' object in the original list.

How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dict to group, using the first element as the key and appending the third elements:

```
l = [["a", "foo", "bar"], ["a", "dog", "cat"], ["b", "foo", "bar"], ["c", "foo", "bar"]]
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for a, b, c in l:
    d[a].append(c)

print([[k] + v for k,v in  d.items()])
```

That presumes you only consider the first element to account for a dupe, if you wanted to keep order and remove dupes including the third elements:

```
l = [["a", "foo", "bar"], ["a", "dog", "cat"], ["a", "dog", "cat"], ["b", "foo", "bar"], ["c", "foo", "bar"],["b", "foo", "bar"]]

from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict

d = defaultdict(OrderedDict)
for a, b, c in l:
    d[a][c] = None

print([[k] + list(v) for k,v in  d.items()])
```

If order is irrelevant just use a *set* and `d[a].add(c)`